# Generate document from docx template with conversion to PDF - text overlaps each other

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, xdocreport

I have a strange problem.
In my application I have couple .docx template. Genering .docx files works fine but when I convert those to .PDF text behave strange.

This is .docx file:

[image: This is docx file]

and .PDF file looks in that way:
[image]

I using **xdocreport** library with .docx templates
How to fix this?

Comment: How do you generate the PDFs ? Using the default Word Save as PDF or something else ?

Comment: I use **void convert( IContext context, Options options, OutputStream out )** from **fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.IXDocReport**

Comment: Could you please tell us what a PDF saving in word does for a docx generated report ?

Comment: @edi9999 : I have two options in my app - Download .docx and .pdf. Implementation of download .pdf is almost the same like .doc but in last line of my service to .docx generation I have **report.process(context, output)** and **report.convert(context, options, output)** in PDF. **report** is **IXDocReport** object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change xdocreport version from **1.0.2** to **l.0.0** and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of XDocReport do you use? If you are using 1.0.3 (not-released), I have improved the line height of the text for PDF converter. Perhaps there are a bug? I suggest you to create a XDocReport issue by attaching your docx which causes the problem.

Comment: I use 1.0.2 version. You suggest attaching docx file in this topic or create issue on XDoxReport page?

Comment: Please create issue on XDocReport website.